# Why Expres Async Errors send different result as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I found a nice npm package by the name of Express Async Errors which according to the documentation, it's really nice to use.
However, if I implement it, the server will crash.
Here is my Route handler code

*Controller*

```
const { Genre } = require("../models");
const { StatusCodes } = require("http-status-codes");


const getGenre = async (req, res) => {
  const genre = await Genre.findById({ _id: req.params.id });

  if (!genre) {
    return res.status(StatusCodes.BAD_REQUEST).json({
      message: "The genre with the given ID was not found.",
    });
  }

  res.status(StatusCodes.OK).json({ status: "success", data: genre });
};
```

```
*router*

const express = require("express");
const { authenticate, admin } = require("../middleware");

const router = express.Router();
const { schemaValidator } = require("../middleware");
const validateRequest = schemaValidator(true);

const { genres } = require("../controllers");
const { getAllGenres, getGenre, createGenre, updateGenre, deleteGenre } =
  genres;

  .route("/genres")
  .get(getAllGenres)
```

*Main Application Entry*

```
require("express-async-errors");
//Routers
const routers = require("./router");
const connectDB = require("./DB/connect");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.use(config.get("URI"), routers);
app.use(notFoundMiddleware);

const start = async () => {
  const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
  const connectionString = config.get("mongoDB.connString");

  await connectDB(connectionString)
    .then(() => DBdebug(`Connected to MongoDB: ${connectionString}`))
    .catch(() => console.log("MongoDB connection failure"));

  app.listen(port, () => debug(`Listening on port ${port}...`));
};

start();
```

Above code is imported into index.js together with express-async-errors.

According to the document, if I create an error, express-async-errors has to handle this without crashing the application. My question is what I'm doind wrong???

I shut down the Mongo-driver just to create a scenario that the server is down with a status 503.

```
MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
    at Function.Model.$wrapCallback (/Volumes/Seagate/lib/model.js:5087:32)
    at /Volumes/Seagate/lib/query.js:4510:21
    at /Volumes/Seagate/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:32:5
From previous event:
    at promiseOrCallback (/Volumes/Seagate/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:31:10)
    at model.Query.exec (/Volumes/Seagate/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:4509:10)
    at model.Query.Query.then (/Volumes/Seagate/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:4592:15)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

Instead of above error, I should see "Something went wrong" as the default message in Postman without crashing the application.

Can someone point me to the right direction?

NB: The link which I had used us is **https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-async-errors**

Thank you very much in advanced.

Comment: Please show the actual code that gets the error in it as asynchronous errors would have to be done properly in order to propagate to Express Async.  And, show the code where you're using Express Async and also provide a link to the Express Async module on NPM (as I don't see any module with that specific name).

Comment: @jfriend00 I have updated my question with your request. I will still pending for eventually comment or remarks.

Comment: What exactly do you do to artificially create the error?  And, where in your code does the error actually happen?  Is the error occuring in `connectDB()` or in some query your code is doing?  Please point us to the actual code where the error occurs.

Comment: @jfriend00, thank you for your attention. I have found a solution for my question and I'm going to answer it know, if you have any comment about my answer, please feel free to do that. By comments I could learn!!

Answer (score 0):

After two days of researching my problem, I finally convinced my self that the problem was me and found a solution for this particular matter.

I have created an ErrorHandlerMiddleware and in the particular middleware I check if the error is an instance of MongooseError object, if this is the case, I just send for now an custom message.

See code below:

```
const { StatusCodes } = require("http-status-codes");
const { CustomApiError } = require("../errors");
const Mongoose = require("mongoose");

const errorHandlerMiddleware = (err, req, res, next) => {
  console.log("errorMiddleWare");
  if (err instanceof CustomApiError) {
    return res.status(err.statusCode).json({ message: err.message });
  }

  if (err instanceof Mongoose.Error) {
    return res.status(StatusCodes.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).json({
      message: "There is a technical problem, please try again later",
    });
  }
};

module.exports = { errorHandlerMiddleware };
```

In main application entry, I just pass errorHandlerMiddleware as a argument reference in app.use.

See code below

```
require("express-async-errors");
//Routers
const routers = require("./router");
const connectDB = require("./DB/connect");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.use(config.get("URI"), routers);
app.use(notFoundMiddleware);
app.use(errorHandlerMiddleware);


const start = async () => {
  const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
  const connectionString = config.get("mongoDB.connString");

  await connectDB(connectionString)
    .then(() => DBdebug(`Connected to MongoDB: ${connectionString}`))
    .catch(() => console.log("MongoDB connection failure"));

  app.listen(port, () => debug(`Listening on port ${port}...`));
};

start();
```

And this is the final result in PostMan:

[image: POSTMAN RESULT]

If there are any comments regarding this solution, feel free to do this.
By comments and can learn more!!!

Thank you in advanced and keep coding!!!!